# Autocovariances for a general stationary ARMA process

Tags: time-series, stationarity, arma

In Van der Vaart's Time Series notes, he states the following:[image]

How does one solve theoretically, at least, a system of infinite dimensions? ( $h\in \mathbb{Z}$)Also, should I understand the $l$ index as in $\mathbb{Z}$ or in $\{1,...,p\}$ for an ARMA$(p,q)$?

Any help would be appreciated.